# Jmeter 5.4.1 failing for 204 response

Tags: http, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

one of my services are returning the below response

```
Thread Name:User Registration 1-1
Sample Start:2021-04-13 22:26:37 AEST
Load time:1223
Connect Time:0
Latency:0
Size in bytes:118
Sent bytes:1006
Headers size in bytes:118
Body size in bytes:0
Sample Count:1
Error Count:1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""):
Response code:204
Response message:No Content


HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null
```

And Jmeter marks it as failed. Note there is no explicit Response Assertion added.

The default assertion result is as below.

Assertion error:false
Assertion failure:true
Assertion failure message:Test failed: code expected to equal /

****** received  : 20[[[4]]]

****** comparison: 20[[[0]]]

/

not sure why Jmeter is comparing the result with 200 without I specifying the

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter Assertions obey [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide) therefore even if you don't have assertion added directly as a child of a Sampler but the Sampler is in scope of an Assertion - the assertion will be applied to the sampler (and in fact to all Samplers in its scope)

[image]

So make sure to double check your Test Plan and see if there are any [Response Assertions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) which check response code to be `200`

If there is one - be aware that you can configure it to accept both `200` and `204` statuses

[image]

Comment: Yeah! thanks for your response. I had an assertion for 200 up in the tree which enforced the assertion on the request which was failing for 204